# Jmeter with ZK framework

Tags: jmeter, comet, zk

I need to do a Load test on application which is built on ZK framework.

When i record a script which performs below action

```
a. User Login 
b. Select Role
c. Open and Create Record
d. Log out.
```

When i run the script with multiple users say 10 users then scripts create 10 records in application.
But after some random duration  say 4-5 hours later same script does not create any record even though all requests are shown as passed. Script also records COMET request (Ajax Push)

I am not able to figure out the reason.

Comment: Would you like to provide the sample, esp. of how you "Open and Create Record" and the test script?
You may also check the memory or quota of database or so on to prevent the possibility that the records are opened and created in fact, but not saved properly.

Answer (score 0):

Read this which explains how ids work :

- http://books.zkoss.org/index.php?title=Small_Talks/2012/January/Execute_a_Loading_or_Performance_Test_on_ZK_using_JMeter
- http://blog.zkoss.org/index.php/2013/08/06/zk-jmeter-plugin/